# How do you get a black-colored border around a bounding box?

Tags: color, boxes, box, colorbox

Below, we see an example of the `\bbox` command.

```tex
$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]
{
e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1+\frac{x}{n} \right)^n
\qquad (2) 
}
$$
```

[image]

Note that the color for the borders of the box is `solid red`.

What is the correct syntax for **solid black**?

The LaTeX language has somewhat unforgiving syntax rules.

At most one of the following strings of text is considered to be syntactically correct:

- `solid black`
- `solid-black` with a hyphen (`-`)
- `Black` (with a large upper-case letter `B`)
- `black` (omitting the word `solid`)
- `blk`
- `BLK`
- `bk`
- `b`
- `RGB(0, 0, 0)`

The string of text for the color **black** must be syntactically correct.

The specification for the color black must adhere to the syntax rules.

Comment: I remember you that LaTeX is not MathJaX. I have seen your code (like as example) in **math.se** community. **What is your minimal working example**?

Comment: If this is LaTeX, you should not use `$$…$$` but either `\[…\]` or a `amsmath` environment. But because there once again isn't a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) I'm not sure, that is is LaTeX.

Comment: @cabohah I am sure that the code is not LaTeX.

Comment: @Sebastiano If it is also not TeX but MathJaX, the question if off-topic.

Comment: @cabohah Look here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference -> Highlighting equation. It is the same code of the user.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is related with MathJaX: see Highlighting equation to the link https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: `\bbox` is not a standard LaTeX command. So you either need to provide the definition for it or state which package you used that defines it. Otherwise, this question will probably be closed for not including enough information or being off-topic (if it is indeed MathJax based if assumed in other comments).

Comment: You wrote, "The LaTeX language has somewhat unforgiving syntax rules." What exactly are you complaining about? The `\bbox` command? Note that it's *not* LateX...

Answer (score 3):

Here's a LaTeX-based solution. It employs the `\boxed` macro of the [amsmath](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for '\boxed' macro, to be used in math mode
\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt} % default line width: 0.4pt
\boxed{
  e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty} \Bigl( 1+\frac{x}{n} \Bigr)^n \qquad (2)
}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -2):

Writing `solid` or `solid black` instead of `solid red` seems to work well.

```tex
$\bbox[5px, border: 2px solid]{\sin(x)}$  


$\bbox[20px, border: 2px solid]{\sin(x)}$  


$\bbox[80px, border: 2px solid]{\sin(x)}$  


$\bbox[160px, border: 10px solid black]{\sin(x)}$
```

[image: a screen capture of four different bordered boxes containing text for the sine-function]

Comment: Sorry, I don't see that this works with LaTeX. Which package is needed to make it work in LaTeX? Please show a working example.